# Manifest package and applicationID can differ from real java packages of the application?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest

Let's analyze this situation:

Manifest package and application ID on gradle file: `com.myweb.mysuperapppackagenamewithaso`

Real java packages inside the sourcecode of my app:

```
com.mysourcecode.package1
com.mysourcecode.package2
```

with the MainActivity here:

```
com.mysourcecode.package1.MainActivity.java
```

Is this possible and safe? Manifest package and applicationID can differ from real java packages of the application?

Comment: Does this https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html help?

Answer (score 0):

Below given are the three things which we need to think about,

```
   applicationId: BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID
   packageName: getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
   Java package: BuildConfig.class.getPackage().toString()
```

`getPackageName` gives the same `applicationId` which is created at the final moment from the gradle file and it `overrides` the `AndroidManifest` package. The final **AndroidManifest contains the same applicationId**.The getPackageName is the same as the applicationId as the applicationId overrides the packageName in the AndroidManifest at the final moment.

But for the Java code, the package is same as the project structure. The package that is used in your source code to refer to your `R class`, and to resolve any relative activity, service registrations, continues to be called the package as defined in your manifest. So, the AndroidManifest should have the package same as Java package to resolve relative activity, service.

So, with the same java package, we can create any number of APKs with all unique applicationId.

Example : [application flavors](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html)

Reference : [Android Package Name Vs Application ID](https://blog.mindorks.com/android-package-name-vs-application-id-ad95b08815a6)

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand you.  To clarify... Manifest package and applicationID can differ from real java packages of the application?

Comment: yes,  applicationID can differ from real java packages of the application. For example : if your application package is com.abc.cdf and if you have a flavor like QA, your applicationId in QA build will be like com.abc.cdf.QA